# SQL Server: Nullable bit, why doesn't field<>'true' not work as expected?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about SQL syntax that I haven't been able to find an answer to (although I might be searching for the wrong things altogether).

I have a table, called Members with a `nullable bit` field called "`HasDroppedOut`".

I now find that if I select members like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE HasDroppedOut<>'true'
```

OR like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE (HasDroppedOut IS NULL OR HasDroppedOut='false')
```

I get different results.  This is because some rows contain NULL fields for the IsDroppedOut column and they get excluded in the first query, but get included in the second one.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is? What aspect am I not grasping here?

Comment: remove closing brackets on where clause and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of `'true'` is not `'false' OR NULL`.  A `NULL` value conceptually represents a value whose value is not known at all.  In other words, we do not know if it be `true` or `false`.  So it does not make good sense to lump `NULL` and `false` records together.

A more meaningful comparison would be to equate the following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE HasDroppedOut <> 'true'
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE HasDroppedOut = 'false'
```

Both of these queries would not include the `NULL` records, and so these `NULL` records would not be part of the comparison at all.

Comment: For the OP's environment, the answer may well be that `NULL` can be categorised as `FALSE`. This isn't always true, but I can give a good example. At our office we have an Opt-In for customers to receive marketing for us. On the website, this has to be ticked (or left unticked) which results in a 1 or 0 value in the `bit` column, but if the customer is being spoken to over the phone it has to be asked. If the operator doesn't ask, the on-screen field is left blank (rather than Yes or No). In this case, as we haven't asked, `NULL` is treated as `0` (even though they are not the same value).

Comment: @Larnu Interesting, but the OP gave no such context in the question.

Comment: I know they didn't, the comment is in response to your comment about that `NULL` and `FALSE` should not be lumped together. There are definitely times that they can be; the main thing is that you have knowledge of the data. In some environments, `NULL` itself can have a "known" value. I'm not at all saying your answer is wrong; you are indeed right that `NULL` and `<> 'true'` are not the same. I'm just adding further input, which might explain the OP's thought process, and where the two *could* be seen as "equal".

Comment: @Larnu While some of your comments may be right, I think you are over answering the question.  The confusion in the OP appears to simply be about what `NULL` represents, not whether your company's website logically decides to treat `NULL` and `false` as the same thing.  They are not the same thing inside SQL Server.

Comment: I wasn't disputing that at all. Just adding an extra "2 cents". :)

Comment: Hi, in our context the "null" value and the "false" value are indeed the same logical thing. The column can be null because some users do not see this functionality and cannot see the checkbox related to this column anyway. If I would design this application today, I would have just set a default value of 'false' to this column, but alas, we have to make do with what we have :-). Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

When comparing to a `NULL` you have to use `IS (NOT) NULL`. If you use a `=`, `<>` or `!=` operator on a NULL, The returned result in UNKNOWN.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @bit bit = NULL;

SELECT CASE @Bit WHEN 0 THEN 'Yes'
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'No'
                 ELSE 'Eh?'
       END AS StatedValue,
       CASE WHEN @Bit <> 1 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN @Bit <> 0 THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Eh?'
       END AS UnstatedValue;
```

Notice that both return the value `'Eh?'` because the comparison to `NULL` returns NULL.

So, for this example, you'd need to do:

```
DECLARE @bit bit = NULL;

SELECT CASE WHEN @Bit <> 1 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN @Bit <> 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN @Bit IS NULL THEN 'Neither'
            ELSE 'Eh?'
       END AS CheckedValue;
```

Comment: The OP's question is why does `Column <> 'True'` and `Column IS NULL OR Column = 'False'` yield different results. The reason being that the expression `Column <> 'True'`does not return a TRUE where the value is `NULL`, where as `Column IS NULL OR Column = 'False'` does.

Comment: I got you...I wasn't thinking in terms of that :-)